# Is there an idiomatic way to test array equality in Coffeescript?

Tags: arrays, coffeescript, equality

The expression

```
[1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]
```

evaluates to `false` in *Coffeescript* but is there a concise, idiomatic way to test array equality?

Comment: I don't know much about coffeescript, but you seem to be testing the equality of the objects with the `==` instead of individual array values.

Comment: someone should note here that `==` in coffeescript gets evauated to `===` in javascript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are dealing with arrays of numbers, and you know that there are no nulls or undefined values in your arrays, you can compare them as strings:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3]

console.log "#{a}" is "#{b}" # true
console.log '' + a is '' + b # true
```

Notice, however, that this will break as soon as you start comparing arrays of other things that are not numbers:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['1,2', 3]

console.log "#{a}" is "#{b}" # true
```

If you want a more robust solution, you can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
arrayEqual = (a, b) ->
  a.length is b.length and a.every (elem, i) -> elem is b[i]

console.log arrayEqual [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]   # true
console.log arrayEqual [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, '3'] # false
console.log arrayEqual [1, 2, 3], ['1,2', 3]  # false
```

Notice that it's first comparing the lengths of the arrays so that `arrayEqual [1], [1, 2, 3]` doesn't return true.

Comment: I like the Array::every solution but IIRC that method isn't supported in IE < 9 (yeah, I wish I didn't have to care, but…)

Comment: @PirateRob Yeah, that might be a problem. I personally stopped commenting "beware that this might not work in IE" because a lot of times it doesn't make sense; there is a lot of mobile JS development, Node.js and whatnot, so, without previous information i wont even comment on the IE compatibility. If you _do_ need to care about IE but would rather still use newer JS things, you can degrade a bit the experience of IE users only and conditionally include a "shim", like [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/), for all those goodies :)

Comment: Also, you could use Underscore's implementation of [`every`](http://underscorejs.org/#all), which will guarantee cross-browser compatibility for a very low cost :)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind introducing an [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) dependency you could use some of it's utilities.  It's not massively elegant, but I can't think of an easier way to do it with plain coffeescript:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
b = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
equal = a.length == b.length and _.all( _.zip( a, b ), ([x,y]) -> x is y )
```

Comment: Only improvement I could think of would be to use coffeescript's destructuring assignment: `_.all(x is y for [x, y] in _.zip( a, b ))`

Comment: Beware that [`_.all`](http://underscorejs.org/#all) _needs_ an iterator function. This example [breaks](http://jsfiddle.net/W5THS/) for me in both Firefox and Chrome as it is now ("iterator is not a function" is thrown in FF). Luckily, it's easy to [fix it](http://jsfiddle.net/W5THS/1/): `_.all _.zip(a, b), ([x, y]) -> x is y` :)

Comment: Unluckily, using `_.zip` will cause this solution to compare `[1, 2, 3, undefined]` and `[1, 2, 3]` [as equal](http://jsfiddle.net/W5THS/2/) :(

Comment: @epidemian Good point - obviously I didn't test this out before posting.  I'll fix.

Comment: I wish people would get out of the habit of using _ -- it breaks when you go to the node command line...

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't consider this idiomatic but this would be a way of doing it without adding an extra library:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [22, 3, 4]

areEqual = true
maxIndex = Math.max(a.length, b.length)-1
for i in [0..maxIndex]
    testEqual = a[i] is b[i]
    areEqual = areEqual and testEqual

console.log areEqual
```

A cleaner approach would be using JavaScript's [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function. This is a bit shorter but I am not sure all browsers support reduce.

```
a = [1, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 3, 4, 5]

maxIndex = Math.max(a.length, b.length)-1
areEqual = true
[0..maxIndex].reduce (p, c, i, ar) -> areEqual = areEqual and (a[i] is b[i])

console.log "areEqual=#{areEqual}"
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works great and requires no dependencies:

```
arrayEqual = (ar1, ar2) ->
  JSON.stringify(ar1) is JSON.stringify(ar2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/). If you happen to be using that:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3]
Object.equal(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function returns `true` if arrays have same length and all values with same index have same value. It throws an error if either argument isn't an array.

```
isArray = Array.isArray || (subject) ->
    toString.call(subject) is '[object Array]'

compareArrays = (a, b) ->
    unless isArray(a) and isArray b
        throw new Error '`arraysAreEqual` called with non-array'

    return false if a.length isnt b.length

    for valueInA, index in a
        return false if b[index] isnt valueInA

    true
```